# Windows 10 Bluetooth CPU priority

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, headset

**How can I set high priority for bluetooth process/service in Windows 10?** In Windows 7 ralink have process which have default high, but here is not any process connected with BT, without that I have delay on my BT headset :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"svchost.exe - k bthsvcs" is the exact process that you need to act on if you wish to ensure High CPU Priority especially for things like A2DP/AptX and ensuring low latency as well as high audio quality.
This was the reason I had to find out, as Games where making my Bluetooth Headphones skip and drop quality despite absolutely fine signal.

I used the Free (Nag's a little however) program Process Lasso to automate setting the process to High Priority. Problem Solved for me :)

Please note some programs do not separate each Service and just show "svchost.exe"

Comment: Does this answer/process also apply to bluetooth mouse/keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

In Command Prompt execute `tasklist /svc /fi “imagename eq svchost.exe”` to see the list of process IDs.

Find the 'bthserv' service and notice the PID. Then Press CTRL + SHIFT + ESC, select the corresponding PID and set it to high priority.

Comment: Thank you for the end to end solution. So far so good.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the details tab of task Manager.

1. Press CTRL + SHIFT + ESC
2. In the window that pops up, click details tab.
3. Right click the service you want.
4. Mouse over Set Priority.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. This answers the specific question that was bolded of "How can I set high priority for bluetooth process/service in Windows 10?" Maybe because it didn't solve a problem that wasn't described here?

Comment: I gave it an up vote. This is the root cause of many bluetooth issues.

Comment: I'm guessing because it doesn't identify which process should be prioritized, so it does not in fact answer the specific question.

Comment: The question is about a headset.  Your answer is about a mouse.

Comment: @Praesagus: This answer is not about a mouse. It is, in fact, not about a specific service at all.