# Wireless keyboard occasionally stops typing... and then types every character it didn't type at once when shook

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, debug, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

My logitech keyboard stops working every 5-20 minutes.  During the time it stops working, if I type on it, even typing hundreds of words, as soon as I vigorously shake the keyboard, everything I had typed appears on screen all at once, and the keyboard at least briefly resumes normal operations.  Now, this sounds like a simple mechanical defect, but I've had it for years, and even after buying a new logitech keyboard, and briefly trying other brands of keyboards, every wireless keyboard that connects to my computer suffers the same bug immediately. What could possibly be happening here?

EDIT: I used to use a direct bluetooth connection, now I use a usb bluetooth receiver. Under both systems the bug occured.

Comment: "every wireless keyboard that connects to my computer suffers the same bug immediately"   Bug / hardware fault in the USB port or controller.

Comment: If that's true, I wonder how the OP's computer can tell when they're shaking the keyboard. Does the keyboard communicate the shaking motion to the computer?

Comment: Does your keyboard use a 2.4 GHz receiver or a Bluetooth receiver, you should edit your question, and avoid replying with a comment.

Comment: If you are shaking the keyboard near the desk, that could do it. You say the fault is with any keyboard you attach.  Also shaking the keyboard could cause another transmit.

Comment: It is strange that the keyboard "stores hundreds of typed words", I'd be very suprised if it has that much memory onboard. I'd suspect something is funky with the computer's operating system. More so if it happens with several keyboards.

Comment: Try booting in Safe mode to check for a bad third-party software. Try also to change the position of the keyboard, theorizing that shaking helps by moving the keyboard to a better spot.

Comment: Does the same issue happen with a wired keyboard. Or with the keyboard in another computer?

Comment: Safe mode does nothing, a wired keyboard does work.

Comment: Does placement of the keyboard matter?

Answer (score 1):

My old cheap Logitech keyboard does the same thing, started about a year ago and I've had it for about 8 years. It is the keyboard, not a driver or dongle issue as the mouse still works and uses the same dongle and drivers obviously. If I gently pick it up and angle it, then put it back down, it works. Sometimes I have to shake it. I've tried rotating the batteries but that doesn't work so it is not a bad connection there. More than likely, it is a bad connection somewhere inside the unit. It may use elastomeric connections which always fail over time, like on the PS3 controllers. I also have a better K540 Logitech keyboard and M310 mouse that never fail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Grasping at straws here...

- Bluetooth driver update?
- Are these keyboards the kind with a built-in trackball/trackpad?  If so, then maybe the shaking is moving the trackball or somehow triggering the trackpad which makes the characters appear.  It would be interesting to know if moving the mouse also makes the characters appear.
- Can you try moving the computer to a different location (different room, different building) to see if that makes a difference?  Maybe there is some sort of electromagnetic interference going on.
- What happens if you just let the keyboard sit for a long time instead of shaking it when it stops working?  Do the characters ever appear or do they only appear after shaking it?  If so, then I agree with @vonbrand that it is probably an OS issue.
- Does the bug occur with a wired keyboard?  If so, then it is probably an OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a lot of processes running in background that are taking priority over your Bluetooth activities.

You need to identify the process/service that is handling I/O from Bluetooth and set it to a higher priority (make it Realtime for the best results).

Steps below are from [Mike's answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1028992/663159)

For this,checkout the details tab of task Manager.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. In the window that pops up, click details tab.
3. Right click the service you want.
4. Mouse over Set Priority.

[image]

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

The facts seem to be:

- All wireless keyboard lose connection until shaken
- Problem still happens when booting in Safe mode, so this isn't caused by a
  third-party product.

Since shaking keyboards shouldn't matter to the internal electronics, or at least not
to more than one such keyboard, my conclusion is that the difference is in the
placement of the keyboard.

I think that by shaking the keyboard you move it where there is less interference,
or that reception is better, so the keyboard regains the connection to the
computer and can transfer the keys accumulated in its buffer.

I suggest checking why the usual place reserved for the keyboard is problematic.
Perhaps it is placed near a unit that sometimes emits strong electromagnetic
interference.
Or perhaps it is just nearer to the wireless dongle.

Comment: Like a microwave oven...

Comment: Good hypothesis, but whether I move the keyboard 15 feet away, or right next to the receiver, its still has the freeze until I shake it occur.

Comment: Rather than violently shaking, what happens when just floating it around above the desk?